# Socket connection from WatchOS 2 and CFStream

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

I have to connect a remote server via tcp socket from the Watch.

I have already written a piece of code using CFStream which works perfectly from the Watch simulator.

When I run it on the Watch I get this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Can't assign requested address (Code = 49)

when I try to open the connection to the server using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost`.

The Apple documentation declares that `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` is

> Available in watchOS 2.0 and later.

so I expected that it had should work but I have found this Apple's engineer answer which confirms that there is no way to open a tcp connection from the Watch:

[Socket communication does not work real Apple Watch](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19399)

Can anyone clarify and help me to understand?

Supposing that I cannot open a tcp connection from the Watch, what kind of alternatives have I, since I cannot use [NSURLSession]?

I could use one of the communication methods provided by [WCSession] but do they work when the iPhone app either is not running or is not in foreground?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [WCSession's sendMessage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:) APIs to wake the iOS app up in the background and have it do the Stream work for you.

Comment: Yes, it's what I am already doing. It's awkward but it's actually working. As expected, speed and throughput are pretty low (both simulator and Watch) and I am struggling to heavy filtering not necessary messages. Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm in the same condition... then I use the phone as bridge for TCP communication but the communication is very slow when the phone is in standby.