# Real Watch device can't connect to server using TCP stream, but all works on simulator

Tags: ios, stream, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have an app that should connect to the server using `CFReadStreamRef` and `CFWriteStreamRef`. All works great on simulator, but not on real device(tested on 4 watches). And I'm not even have any idea of where to look. Internet works on watch, cause map app works good.

If you have any ideas don't hesitate to share them with me, literally ANY ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket connection from WatchOS 2 and CFStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367222/socket-connection-from-watchos-2-and-cfstream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicate: [Socket connection from WatchOS 2 and CFStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367222/socket-connection-from-watchos-2-and-cfstream)

it won't work according to Apple Developer straight on the watch but you can do that work on iphone and send over data to watch usign WatchConnectivity Framework

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19399